# How change the fixed CI/CD variables from repo settings by request?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to know if is it possible change the CI/CD variables assigned in repo settings by request. I know previously i can pass env variables by curl request to trigger the pipeline.

But now i have another situation which an automatic build and a docker image is pushed to a private registry happen when the master or dev branch suffers a merge. To do this, i use the CI/CD variables already setted.

**And oftenly i will create a new registry, which it is done automatically in a bash script. After this what i'd like is setup the new keys accesses to the gitlab repo via request or other automatic way**.

If someone could help me with some idea, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken this it what you are looking for:

> Project-level Variables API
>
> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html